# Randperm Paired Columns of a Matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, permutation

I was wondering if it would be possible to use randperm to re-arrange a cell matrix consisting of paired identical columns. For example,

```
S S S S S S L L L L L L
1 1 3 3 5 5 1 1 3 3 5 5
```

into

```
S S L L S S S S L L L L
3 3 1 1 5 5 1 1 5 5 3 3
```

Edit: I meant it more like having paired columns (or mini-blocks) randomly permuted to form a matrix like the one above.

```
S S    S S    S S    L L    L L    L L   
1 1    3 3    5 5    1 1    3 3    5 5
```

Thank You.

Comment: Can we see your approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c = {'S' 'S' 'S' 'S' 'S' 'S' 'L' 'L' 'L' 'L' 'L' 'L';
      1   1   3   3   5   5   1   1   3   3   5   5}; %// data: cell array
N = 2; %// number of columns per block
d = reshape(c, 2*size(c,1), []); %// pack each group of N columns into a single column
ind = randperm(size(d,2));  %// random permutation of packed-column indices
result = d(:,ind); %// apply those indices
result = reshape(result, size(c,1), []); %// unpack columns
```

An example result is

```
result = 
    'L'    'L'    'L'    'L'    'S'    'S'    'S'    'S'    'L'    'L'    'S'    'S'
    [1]    [1]    [5]    [5]    [5]    [5]    [3]    [3]    [3]    [3]    [1]    [1]
```

Comment: beated me for a second!

Comment: With identical columns still paired together :)

Comment: @Ben Do all blocks have the same size? If so, you only need two reshapes. I'll get back to you later

Comment: @BenJHC Please see now